# sql error 1241 operand should contain 1 column

Tags: mysql

This is my query

```
select * 
from players 
where sport='football' 
  and position='DEF' 
  and pname!='Binoy Dalal' 
  and pname not in (select player1,player2,player3,player4,player5,player6,player7,player8
                    from team 
                    where sap='60003100009') 
order by price desc;
```

It works fine without the `pname not in ...` clause.

I can't figure out whats wrong cause syntactically it's correct as mysql doesn't show any errors.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot have multiple columns being returned in a subquery like that, so you have several ways that you would have rewrite this query to work.

Either you can *unpivot* the data in the `team` table so you are only returning one column:

```
select * 
from players 
where sport='football' 
  and position='DEF' 
  and pname!='Binoy Dalal' 
  and pname not in (select player1 
                    from team where sap='60003100009'
                    union all
                    select player2
                    from team where sap='60003100009'
                    union all
                    select player3
                    from team where sap='60003100009'
                    union all
                    select player4
                    from team where sap='60003100009'
                    union all
                    select player5
                    from team where sap='60003100009'
                    union all
                    select player6
                    from team where sap='60003100009'
                    union all
                    select player7
                    from team where sap='60003100009'
                    union all
                    select player8
                    from team where sap='60003100009') 
order by price desc;
```

Or you can use a `NOT EXISTS` query:

```
select * 
from players p
where sport='football' 
  and position='DEF' 
  and pname!='Binoy Dalal' 
  and not exists (select *
                  from team t
                  where sap='60003100009' 
                    AND
                    (
                      p.pname = t.player1 OR
                      p.pname = t.player2 OR
                      p.pname = t.player3 OR
                      p.pname = t.player4 OR
                      p.pname = t.player5 OR
                      p.pname = t.player6 OR
                      p.pname = t.player7 OR
                      p.pname = t.player8
                    ))
order by price desc;
```

Or you would have to use multiple `WHERE` filters on the player name:

```
select * 
from players 
where sport='football' 
  and position='DEF' 
  and pname!='Binoy Dalal' 
  and pname not in (select player1 
                    from team where sap='60003100009')
  and pname not in (select player2 
                    from team where sap='60003100009')
  and pname not in (select player3 
                    from team where sap='60003100009')
  and pname not in (select player4 
                    from team where sap='60003100009')
  and pname not in (select player5 
                    from team where sap='60003100009')
  and pname not in (select player6 
                    from team where sap='60003100009')
  and pname not in (select player7 
                    from team where sap='60003100009')
  and pname not in (select player8 
                    from team where sap='60003100009')
order by price desc;
```

However, ideally you should consider normalizing the `team` table so you have one column with the player name and another column that assigns them a player number. Similar to this:

```
create table team
(
  player varchar(50),
  playerNumber int
);
```

Then when you are searching the team data you only have to join on one column instead of 8 different columns.

Comment: Extra +1 for the suggestion to normalize the table.

Comment: thanks a ton....works like a charm
i cant normalize this table now but i'll keep it in mind, next time i am working on something similar